# Wrapping text with that isn't wrapped with any HTML tag (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery

I have some text in the following div: `.wpbdp-listing-single`
The text has nothing wrapping it. How to trap an HTML tag around it? (without wrapping the other elements that do have html tags?

Comment: Would a sample input be `<div class="wpbdp-listing-single">foo <em>leave me alone</em> bar</div>` ?

Comment: @Dan Dascalescu Yes, exactly like that plus more stuff with other tags. I just want to wrap "foo."

Comment: How about `bar`? Would [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228084/1269037) do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to only wrap text-only elements of that div. Here's jQuery code that does that:

```
$('.wpbdp-listing-single').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
})​.wrap('<b></b>');​​​​​​​​​​
```

Unlike `.children()`, `.contents()` will return text nodes as well, and you can filter for text nodes *only* by testing for the `nodeType` property.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/YkgLa/